# How to search for / query an SQS queue element that matches criteria

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-sqs, fifo

I would like to search for the "first" N elements of an SQS queue that matches specific criteria. Doesn't really have to be the first ones, approximate is fine.

*SQS FIFO* queues support this, but here's the catch: I would like to retain the "standard" SQS methodology of continuing to process additional elements while the invisible one is being processed (and also avoid the SQS FIFO restriction on number of times an element with specific critera can be enqueued).

Essentially, I **DO NOT** need *FIFO-ness*. I only need to reach into the queue and get the first element that meets my needs.

Note that since these criteria are relatively dynamic, creating SQS queues on the fly will ***NOT*** work, as

1. this actually costs money
2. SQS queue counts are subject to limits
3. there is a multi-minute delay before new queues are available

Comment: *"SQS FIFO queues support this"* ...how?

Comment: You can specify a message ID, WHICH i believe to be a free-form string. You can then make the IDs essentially match your predefined search criteria's space.

Comment: Are you referring to the FIFO `ReceiveRequestAttemptId` parameter? I don't think you will be able to use that in the way you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to 'search' messages in an Amazon SQS queue.

A `ReceiveMessage()` call will retrieve one or more messages, but there is no ability to control *which* messages will be returned.

While *Message Attributes* can be attached to a message, they cannot be specified when retrieving messages.

If you have a need to process particular messages first, then you will need to **put them into a separate queue**. Then, have your app read from that queue before the normal queue.

Comment: Durn, was hoping for some API call I missed. It's really too bad that standard queues cannot support more of the FIFO functionality.